# redis command takes long time to fetch data

Tags: windows, batch-file, redis, redis-cli

I have created a bat file for deleting custom data from Redis DB. I have following code

```
@echo off & cls
title :Redis Service
echo "Redis cache clearing started"
for /F "tokens=*" %%f IN ('redis-cli -h 192.134.56.67 -p 6379 -a MyPassword keys "My.Key.*"') do (
 echo "%%~f"
 redis-cli -h 192.134.56.67 -p 6379 -a MyPassword del "%%~f"
)
echo deletion completed
```

But it takes a long time to execute. How to use SCAN instead of KEY command in above code

Comment: ok.. let me first get this. when running `redis-cli -h 192.134.56.67 -p 6379 -a MyPassword keys "My.Key.*` on its own, does it return a list of strings?

Comment: No. it remains stuck

Comment: Ok so then the issue is not with the script..

Comment: ok. But below command returns data

Comment: for /F "tokens=*" %%f IN ('redis-cli -h 192.134.56.67 -p 6379 -a MyPassword keys  SCAN 0 MATCH "My.Key.*" COUNT 1000 ') do (
  echo "%%~f"
 )

Comment: yes. because you are setting a limit of 1000

Comment: the `KEYS` command is slow if the key space is getting huge. it is not recommended to use `KEYS` command as will block the whole redis server. the recommend practice is to use the `SCAN` command and keep scanning until 0 returned.